# What is the use of "wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty" in Spring Eureka Server?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I was going through a tutorial and I came across with this config in .yml file.

eureka:
client:
registerWithEureka: false
fetchRegistry: false
server:
waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0

Here, what exactly is the purpose of "waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty"? Also what does "fetchRegistry" flag say?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
eureka:
    client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        server:
            waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Basically above three lines tells:

> this instance to not register itself with the Eureka instance it finds, because that instance is.. itself.

Source :[Spring Doc](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka)

Below are the individual statement level meanings:

- Configuration tells eureka(client) to gets the registration information from the eureka server registry, the default is true

> ```
> eureka:
>     client:
>         fetchRegistry: false
> ```

- Configuration tells when the eureka server is started, you cannot wait for the instance registration information from the peer node. How long should it wait?[source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/17089345/)

> ```
> eureka:
>     client:
>         server:
>             waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
> ```

**Usage** : By default euraka server could act as both client and server.This is useful when we run multiple eureka servers to face [SPOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) issues.In this case , eureka could register both other microservice instances and **naming server instances**.